# In Android Studio, how to run a specific Build Variant?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using multiple build variants in my Gradle using flavorDimensions.

When debugging, how do I choose which variant is run when using Android Studio run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Studio has a View simply called as "Build Variants". It is generally along with "1:Project" and "7:Structure" views. Pressing that lets us choose which build variant needs to be executed when running the app.