# How can I deploy production version of an Android app from Android Studio via USB?

Tags: android-studio

I know how to install a debug version and I have source code available. How can I install regular production version, via USB? Without going through F-droid or Google Play or other store?

Comment: If you have AS, you should be able to choose to build a 'release' variant.  Building that variant should execute release specific commands like obfuscation.

Comment: @eimmer Thanks so much! "variant" was key word that allowed me to find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404261/in-android-studio-how-to-run-a-specific-build-variant (if you want you can post an answer and I will accept it).

Comment: Also, for once I posted a blatant duplicate where "mark as duplicate" would be actually useful, but people who keep marking clearly different questions as duplicates this time have not arrived.

Comment: I got you buddy - I've marked it as a duplicate. :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have AS, you should be able to choose to build a 'release' variant. Building that variant should execute release specific commands like obfuscation.